# "Repeated column in mapping for entity" on ID field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm making Spring application with Hibernate and I'm just trying to get relations between my entities working. I set up annotations for all foreign keys and now I get "Repeated column in mapping for entity" error. I was trying to find a solution here on SO, but I didn't really understand some of the answers and I don't think they are applicable to my code. I had this problem earlier with another project, where all ID fields were named just `id` and when I explicitly defined column name by `@Column(name = "")` and typed that name in `@JoinColumn` parameters it worked. Now I had the same error, but defining explicit names for ID fields didn't help.

Here's my entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable, Discussable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "task_id")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_task",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    )
    private Set<User> assigneeUsers;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Status status; //alt + enter

    private Priority priority;

    private Date deadline;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private Task parentTask;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentTask")
    private Set<Task> subtasks;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Type type;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")
    private Channel channel;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;

// getters, setters and default constructor
```

The result I get when trying to compile is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.github.mesayah.assistance.AssistanceApplication.main(AssistanceApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.github.mesayah.assistance.model.Task column: task_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:830) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:870) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:605) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

So I think the problem is with `private Task parentTask;` or `private Set<User> asigneeUsers;` because only these members use mapping for "task_id". But I can't figure out what in particular is wrong with this code.

Comment: shouldnt you use something like parent_tak_id? task_id is the @Id of the table.. this does not make sense

Comment: In the `@JoinColumn` on the ManyToOne you have to define a column name for the link from Task to its parent, not the name of the column you are linking to. Since it is a relation to itself you need to choose a column name that doesn't already exist in the table of Task. As Maciej Kowalski sais you should probably use `@JoinColumn(name = "parent_task_id")`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error that you are seeing:

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: 
com.github.mesayah.assistance.model.Task column: task_id 
(should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

This tells you that the column `task_id` inside the entity `Task` has been associated with more than one property.

You can associate the same column to multiple properties in a mapping; 
however, only one of the mappings can control the persistence behavior while the others are *read-only*.

As a trivial example:

```
public class MyEntity {
  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String name2;
}
```

The property `name` in this example will always be inserted and updated.  This property controls the persistence of the column `NAME`.  The property `name2` will never be inserted nor updated and simply acts as a *read-only* field for column `NAME`.

If I had not included `insertable = false, updatable = false` on the column mapping, then Hibernate would have given the same error message you're seeing.

Now that you understand the technical reasons of the error message, your problem is as Maciej Kowalski mentions.  You should likely have mapped your parent reference differently:

```
@ManyToOne
@Column(name = "parent_task_id")
private Task parentTask;
```

Conceptually, what you're looking for is your child `Task` which has a column `task_id` to also have a second column that references the foreign-key to the parent `Task`.  This foreign key must be stored in a new column, aptly named `parent_task_id`.

Comment: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property?

Comment: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property